# remove attr required with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

can I remove the attr required from input field warranty_duration when I check the checkbox livelongwarranty

```
years warrenty<label id="warrantyDurationlabel"><input name="warranty_duration" type="number" placeholder="aantal jaren garantie" min="1" size="25" required /></label>
  levenlang<label id="livelongwarranty"><input name="livelong_warranty" type="checkbox" onclick="js/warrantyrequired.js" /></label>
```

I have the following jquery:

```
$('#livelong_warranty').change(function () {
if($(this).is(':checked') {
    $('#warranty_duration').removeAttr('required');
} else {
    $('#warranty_duration').attr('required');
}});
```

Comment: `removeAttr()` is fine. But to add the attribute back, you need to give it a value: `.attr('required', true)`

Comment: WIth only one argument, `.attr()` just returns the value, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: There is not `#warranty_duration` and `#livelong_warranty` in your html.

Comment: @Barmar I addad true to .attr, but that doesn't seem to work, I still get the message that the field warranty_duration is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add id attributes to your inputs because they had no ID's (you can search for names, but I don't think that's what you want).  Name is used primarily for post/get data sent via an HTML/PHP form and id is used to reference, style, and further more JavaScript an element.

```js
$('#livelong_warranty').on('change', function () {
 $('#warranty_duration').attr('required',$('#livelong_warranty').is(":checked"));
 console.log($('#warranty_duration').attr('required'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
years warrenty<label id="warrantyDurationlabel"><input name="warranty_duration" id="warranty_duration" type="number" placeholder="aantal jaren garantie" min="1" size="25" required /></label>
levenlang<label id="livelongwarranty"><input name="livelong_warranty" id="livelong_warranty" type="checkbox" /></label>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but when I select the checkbox livelong_warranty I still get the message that the field warranty_duration is required.

Do I need the script src when I allready use:  jQuery v3.1.1?

Comment: @wes You should only load one version of jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, sadly with 2.1.1 and  3.1.1 it doesn't work

Comment: @wes Did you remember to add `id="warranty_duration"` to the textbox and `id="livelong_warranty"` to the checkbox?

Comment: The code has it backwards. When the checkbox is checked, the input should *not* be required. So it should be `!$('#livelong_warranty').is(":checked")`

Comment: @wes You had another problem: `onclick="js/warrantyrequired.js"` You can't put a script name in `onclick`, it expects actual Javascript code.

Comment: @Barmar can <input type="submit"> interfere with jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/3p0Lp81o/

Comment: if you don't have a submit button, how do you get a message about the field being required?

Comment: @wes Your fiddle doesn't load jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar I have a submit button in fiddle `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="registreren" />`.  Now I get please use post request

Comment: @Barmar I'm sometimes just stupid, forgot to add the new <style src> in my php file. I'm sorry.....